# OwlCarousel2 и dots

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

Сразу к сути. Сделал на слайды анимацию через `animateIn`, после этого пытаюсь адаптивить для мобильных, и на разрешение 768 - я вывел `dots`.Пытаюсь нажать на точку, в итоге ничего не перелистывает. Стоит убрать анимацию и они сразу работают... Кто знает, подскажите, как решить данную проблему ?

Comment: Хотел стать счастливым, но ничего не вышло, никто не знает почему? Это я про то, что было бы неплохо и код хоть какой-то показать...

Comment: var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
 owl.owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  items: 1,
  smartSpeed: 700,
  nav: true,
  navText: '',
  animateIn: 'flipInX'
 });

Comment: с такими настройками все работает (скачал с офф сайта). Нужен реальный пример, чтобы понять, что не так.

Comment: @NeedHate [git](https://github.com/PINKI45/Ruslan/blob/master/README.md) Можете так проверить, если будет так работать, то могу полностью sass стили на этот кусок кинуть. Сам я ток начинающий, верстаю обычные шаблоны, для опыта и практики:) Проблема хоть и не критичная, но хочется в будущем уже знать, как ее решать) И спасибо, что помогаете:)

Comment: Либо весь проект могу залить на хаб, там уже через галп проверить можешь. Если что пиши, нужен или нет:)

Comment: на гите сейчас только html ... или я что-то не вижу. 
Залей весь проект. Думаю, там ничего страшного в проблеме нет, но что-то просто "перекрывает"

Comment: @NeedHate [git](https://github.com/PINKI45/Ruslan) в архив все скинул

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот этом файле в `_media.sass` есть класс `.animated` и в нем отключается всё касательно анимации. Поэтому ничего не работает. Если убрать эти параметры то анимация работает как и должно.

Comment: Спасибо, огромное:) А можно пояснить, для чего отключены анимации на таких разрешения? Или все же правильней отключать анимацию на планшетах и телефонах, так как они не нужны фактически?

Comment: Главная задача сайта, чтобы пользователь достиг конечного результата в получении нужной информации. На мобильных желательно, чтобы все элементы работали быстро. На слабых устройствах анимация всегда будет "подтупливать". Но в случае с transform это уже не так критично. Так что можно потестировать как оно будет на мобильных устройствах.

Comment: Вот оно как, буду знать теперь. От души, помог:) Слушай, я чувствую, что наглею :D Меня интересует по поводу этого шаблона, который я скинул. Там есть 3-я секция(портфолио) и опять же при адаптивности на разрешение 768 возникла проблема с 'hover'om. Долго обьяснять, проще посмотреть. Можешь подсказать, где я напутал стили) Конечно ее можно легко решить, 'col-xs-6' поставить, но на мобильных убого смотреться будет)